# count word occurances in column pig

Tags: hadoop, count, apache-pig

I have a file where line looks something like this.

```
('www.example.com', 'FirstName LastName', '12345', 'Firstname', 'Lastname', '1967-05-16', 'Organization name')
```

With PIG I would like to count how many times same 'Organization name' occurs in the file and output it in the following format

```
'Count Result','www.example.com', 'FirstName LastName', 'Organization name'
```

Here is what I have tried so far, I know I am missing something on the line `countOccurance`, but can't figure out what:

```
data = LOAD 'data' AS (line:chararray);
data = FOREACH data GENERATE line, REPLACE(REPLACE(line, '\\(',''),'\\)','');
data = FOREACH data GENERATE STRSPLIT(line, '\\,') as entity;
grouped = GROUP data BY entity.$6;
countOccurance = FOREACH grouped GENERATE group as entity.$6,COUNT(data);
DUMP countOccurance;
```

Comment: as per current input word count for each splited word will be one only.

Comment: yes but I put this as an example I have a file which contains around million entries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's been a while since I've done anything with pig, but I think you can just do.

```
data = LOAD date USING pigstorage(',') AS (URL:chararray, FULLNAME:chararray, ..., COMPANYNAME:chararray);
data = FOREACH (GROUP data BY COMPANYNAME) GENERATE COUNT(data.COMPANYNAME), data.URL, data.FULLNAME, data.COMPANYNAME;
DUMP data;
```

replace ... with the other column names of course.